# При нажатии на блок добавить класс к другому блоку

Tags: javascript, html

Я новичок в JS, не могу понять почему не работает скрипт. При нажатии на див с классом .main_menu_block , к диву с .mmb_left и .mmb_right должен добавляться класс .show

```js
var main_menu_block = document.getElementsByClassName("main_menu_block");
var mmb_left = document.getElementsByClassName("mmb_left");

main_menu_block.onclick = function() {
  mmb_right.addClass("show"),
    mmb_left.addClass("show");
}
```

```css
.main_menu_block {
  width: 100vh;
  float: right;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: red;
}

.mmb_left,
.mmb_right {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 0.5;
  p {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0.5;
    color: black;
  }
}

.show {
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: black;
  p {
    display: inline-block;
    opacity: 1;
    color: white;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="main_menu_block main_menu_vs">
  <h2>Ведение страницы</h2>
</div>
<div class="mmb_left">
  <p>123</p>
</div>
<div class="mmb_right">
  <p>123</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот решение вашей проблемы:

У вас было две ошибки:

1) `.addClass()` не метод `javascript`, это метод [jQuery](https://jquery.com/).

2) Метод `getElementsByClassName` выбирает все элементы у которых есть заданный класс, если даже у вас такой элемент один то он все ровно возвращает массив результатов. и поэтому ваши элементы нужно взять так `document.getElementsByClassName("main_menu_block")[0]`, первый элемент массива.

```js
var main_menu_block = document.getElementsByClassName("main_menu_block")[0];
var mmb_left = document.getElementsByClassName("mmb_left")[0];
var mmb_right = document.getElementsByClassName("mmb_right")[0];

main_menu_block.onclick = function() {
  mmb_right.className += " show";
  mmb_left.className += " show";
}
```

```css
.main_menu_block {
  width: 100vh;
  float: right;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: red;
}

.mmb_left,
.mmb_right {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.mmb_right p {
  display: none;
  opacity: 0.5;
  color: black;
}

.show {
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: black;
}

.show p {
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 1;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="main_menu_block main_menu_vs">
  <h2>Ведение страницы</h2>
</div>
<div class="mmb_left">
  <p>123</p>
</div>
<div class="mmb_right">
  <p>123</p>
</div>
```